# Does an organisation have to satisfy all key process areas to achieve a maturity level in CMMI?

Tags: project-management-style, process-improvement, cmmi

I have been learning about CMMI and one thing that I'd like to know, say for example an organisation satisfies some key process areas such as Requirements management, software quality assurance. What does the organisation need to include to achieve level 2 maturity.

Answer (score 2):

In order for an organization to reach a maturity level, they are following the Staged Representation of the CMMI. But there is also another representation - the Continuous Representation - that has different requirements. Both are explained.

The Staged Representation allows an organization to achieve maturity level ratings. Every maturity level is associated with a set of process areas. For example, an organization that is Managed (Level 2) is achieving the goals of Configuration Management, Measurement and Analysis, Project Monitoring and Control, Project Planning, Process and Product Quality Assurance, Requirements Management, and Supplier Agreement Management. In order to achieve a certain maturity level, the specific and generic goals of every process area associated with that maturity level (and any lower maturity levels) must be satisfied.

However, there's also a Continuous Representation. This allows an organization to achieve capability level ratings. There are four capability levels, numbered 0 through 3 and named Incomplete, Performed, Managed, and Defined. Process areas are examined individually, and not all process areas may be examined (it could just be a subset of the 16 process areas). Again, the specific and generic goals of the process area can be satisfied, but each process area is examined in isolation from the others, and each process area receives its own capability level.

Answer (score 0):

For maturity level 2, AFAIK, an organization would have to not only have policies in place but ensure that processes are planned and executed according to the policies applicable.  The resources for the project(s) have to be allocated and utilized.  Stakeholders have to be involved in decision making.  The processes must also be monitored, controlled, reviewed and evaluated and repeated continually.